# How to add dynamically circular image view with some specified background color

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on an instant chat application.I have to implement following screen.

[image: Screenshot]

In the screenshot you can see we have a circular image view where we are displaying the profile pic of the user.On profile pic we have a small circle having green color indicating that the user is online.I am implementing the screen using following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding10">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10">

        <com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgContact"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp "
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

        <com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:background="#78dd63" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Neeraj"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
            android:text="Welocme to Almachat" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But i am getting the screen as is given below:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here you can see that green color is not displayed in circle .It is displayed in square.However I have set the color in the design ,in actual practice i want to set it as green using java code when the user will be online .I have taken a circular image view .Still the background color is shown in square.Please guide me how can i fix the issue.

**Solved the Issue:**

Create a drawable named circle_green.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/green_color"
        android:startColor="@color/green_color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/while_color"></stroke>
</shape>
```

**Used it in the background of an imageview**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/padding10">


<com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgContact"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp "
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/online"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgContact"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgContact"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_green" />
```

It is working for me now.

Comment: use relative layout instead of FrameLayout

Comment: @Madhur:Can u please explain in detail?

Comment: Suggested you the same(drawable file as background)

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a CustomImageView like this...

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

public CircularImageView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context,attributeSet);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
    Bitmap finalBitmap;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
        finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                false);
    else
        finalBitmap = bitmap;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
            finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
            finalBitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
            finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
            finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

         return output;
      }
  }
```

And use the imageview class in your xml layout like this...

```
   <com.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/std_img"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

Comment: Please check my xml code.I have already used a circular image view but my problem is when i am setting green background color to a circular image view ,it is not shown as circle,but as square.You can check the screen shot mentioned.

Comment: Use a drawable for background circle.. like this
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
And use this in place of green background color like this...
android:background="@drawable/circle"

Comment: Thanks for the help dear.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this :

```
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUserImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/user_temp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgOnlineIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgUserImage"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgUserImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:src="@drawable/online_indicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is just an example from my app.You can modify it accordingly and it serves your purpose.
* i used a small green image to show as online indicator.

Comment: Even your answer appears to work well but i have used a different approach to fix the issue.Please check my edited code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the powerful **Constraint Layout**.

The advantages are:

1. **Consistency** in different layout sizes.
2. **Simple** to implement.
3. You can **animate** the dot =).

Create a drawable named *circle_green.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/green_color"
        android:startColor="@color/green_color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/while_color"></stroke>
</shape>
```

Align the online dot on your ImageView within the Constraint Layout.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_profile_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_profile_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar_1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/online"
    android:layout_width="12dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
    android:contentDescription="@string/online_status"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/profile_image"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="150"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="@dimen/avatar_profile_radius" />
```

Ignore the warning that the ImageView is not constrained.

Finally, in order to animate, do the following:

```
view.button_home.setOnClickListener {
            //1
            val layoutParams = view.online.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
            val startAngle = layoutParams.circleAngle
            val endAngle = startAngle + 360

            //2
            val anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startAngle, endAngle)
            anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->

                //3
                val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
                val layoutParam = view.online.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                layoutParam.circleAngle = animatedValue
                view.online.layoutParams = layoutParam

                //4
                view.online.rotation = (animatedValue % 360 - 150)
            }
            //5
            anim.duration = 2000

            //6
            anim.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
            anim.start()
        }
```